# Safe a variable @ shopify theme

Tags: themes, shopify

As you can see, in the last row of the code I calculate the basic price per meter of this product. Unfortunately, this price is calculated just once for all variants. To output the special basic price for every product variants. can you help me out how to do this?

```
  <p class="product-single__price product-single__price-{{ section.id }}{% unless current_variant.available %} product-price--sold-out{% endunless %}">
        {% if current_variant.compare_at_price > current_variant.price %}
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
            <s id="ComparePrice-{{ section.id }}">{{ current_variant.compare_at_price | money }}</s>
            <span class="product-price__price product-price__price-{{ section.id }} product-price__sale product-price__sale--single">
              <span id="ProductPrice-{{ section.id }}"    
                itemprop="price" content="{{ current_variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}">
                {{ current_variant.price | money }}
              </span>
              <span class="product-price__sale-label product-price__sale-label-{{ section.id }}">{{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t }}</span>
            </span>                  
        {% else %}
          <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
          <s id="ComparePrice-{{ section.id }}" class="hide">{{ current_variant.compare_at_price | money }}</s>
          <span class="product-price__price product-price__price-{{ section.id }}">
            <span id="ProductPrice-{{ section.id }}"
              itemprop="price" content="{{ current_variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}">
              {{ current_variant.price | money }}
            </span>
            <span class="product-price__sale-label product-price__sale-label-{{ section.id }} hide">{{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t }}</span>
          </span>
        {% endif %}  
        <p class="hint">Grundpreis: {{ product.price | times:current_variant1.title | divided_by:1000 | money}}/Meter</p> 
      </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `Grundpreis` for each variant, then you can do it in the loop like that:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    <p class="hint">Grundpreis: {{ product.price | times:variant.title | divided_by:1000 | money}}/Meter</p> 
{% endfor %}
```